# Find which target framework application is building on?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0, coreclr

I have old .NET Core project. Under application properties the project's Target framework is
`.NET Core 2.0`
[image]

But on the build server We don't have 2.0 SDK installed. Instead we have other SDK versions, like 2.1, 2.2 etc

[image]

The application is building and working fine. Build server is using `dotnet publish -c Release` command to build the application. But how do I know which version is being used to build the application. Is it using the latest version of 2.*, which in this case `2.2.402`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version)

As mentioned in the document:

The process for selecting an SDK version is:

dotnet searches for a global.json file iteratively reverse-navigating the path upward from the current working directory.

dotnet uses the SDK specified in the first global.json found.

dotnet uses the latest installed SDK if no global.json is found.